# Would using hash in python speed up string/char comparison?

Tags: python, hash

I know that converting strings in python can help speed up string comparison. But I'm not sure if my code can be accelerated by converting my strings to hashes.

I am starting with line 1 and looking for all lines that are within a levenshtein distance of 1 and adding them all to a list. So in the below example the first three lines all get added to a list and the fourth line does not. Then I am iterating through that list and comparing the characters found in each string at pos 1,2,3... Finally, I am outputting a string that is sort of like an average such that the first character is an h because it is the most common letter found at char position 1, and the second character is an e because that is the most common second character, and so on.

The problem is that this is with very large amounts of sequencing data, and has already been running for a week on a cluster and has not made very rapid progress.

So, if I convert all strings to hashes first can that be used to find levenshtein distance and then character differences or not. Because from what I can tell this isn't possible with hashes. Thanks.

Example Input file:

```
hello
hallo
helpo
hrowi
```

Example Output file:

```
hello
```

Comment: Why do you think this even *might* be possible with hashes?

Comment: I got a suggestion from a bioinformatics guy in the department that hashes might be used for more rapid searching through a file. And I understand how they might be used for exact matching of strings, but not character comparison and loose string matching.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing. You said Levenshtein distance but then described a way of processing that would make more sense with *Hamming* distance. What would your output be if the input also contained things like "HLLO" and "HELKLO"?

Comment: If all you want is the string built up from the most common letter at each index, you could iterate between indices 0 and (length of the word - 1), counting instances of all characters at i, then building the new string up from the most common occurences

Comment: Another question -- what if there is a tie? What if e.g. 'h' and 'k' are equally common in the first position? Also -- is there a restricted alphabet such as A,T,C,G in your intended application? It would help if you described your actual problem in more detail. For example -- is the problem the length of the lines or the number of files?

Comment: An out-of-the-box solution: split the input file into different files for each position, then sort each file, then count the ocurrences of each letter, keeping the one with the biggest count.

Comment: @JohnColeman you are right, I am essentially just looking at hamming distance as all strings are of the same length and if a letter is equally common all of the matching strings are just thrown out. I realize this is all out of context, but I am doing a lot of other sequencing analysis along with this collapsing, so I'm trying to keep it as simple and understandable as possible.

Comment: @tom unfortunately each string contains information and must be compared using something like levenshtein distance first. After this is done it seems that I am doing what you suggest.

Comment: You could represent all strings into a single tree where each node is a letter. Then for each string in your file, you look at most an edit distance of 1 away while you gather up all the matching strings. Since strings are all the same length the search area is greatly constrained as you don't have to worry about missing letters. Each time you find a matching string, increment a counter at all the nodes. Find greatest node count at each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Edit: I am adding a second version which is less dependent on the bioinformatics perspective but am keeping the first version since for strict bioinformatics it might be better.

Here is a possible answer for the alphabet "ATGC". I based it on the notion of DNA fingerprinting. I have a possibly large list of large strands. I randomly select a subset of those positions to be "fingerprinted". In my test data the strands were of length 10,000 and I randomly picked 100 positions. I form a fingerprint of the characters in the first line at those positions. Then, based on that fingerprint I create a set of "smudged fingerprints" -- which consists of the original fingerprint and those fingerprints at Hamming distance 1. I then iterate through the rest of the list. I first fingerprint the strand and see if it is in the set of smudges. If it is -- then I look if the strand is within Hamming distance 1. If it is -- I update a dictionary I am maintaining at each position, keyed by the characters. Finally I create the summary string. With 10,000 strands each of which has length 10,000 it only takes a few seconds to both create the these strings and compute the summary string:

```
import random

def randDNA(n):
    return ''.join(random.choice("ATGC") for i in range(n))

def mutate(strand,times):
    nucleotides = list(strand)
    n = len(strand)
    for i in range(times):
        j = random.randint(0,n-1)
        nucleotides[i] = random.choice("ATGC")
    return ''.join(nucleotides)

def HammingClose(s,t):
    #assumes s and t are strings of the same length
    #returns True if s,t are Hamming distance at most 1
    #otherwise returns False

    clashes = 0
    for x,y in zip(s,t):
        if x != y:
            clashes += 1
            if clashes > 1: return False
    return True

def takeFingerPrint(strand,places):
    return ''.join(strand[i] for i in places)

def smudges(fp):
    s = set([fp])
    for i,c in enumerate(fp):
        s.update([fp[:i] + d + fp[(i+1):] for d in "ATGC" if d != c])
    return s

def summary(strandList, fpSize = 10):
    n = len(strandList)
    refStrand = strandList[0]
    ncount = 1 #count of refstrand + Hamming-neighbors
    position = {}

    for i,c in enumerate(refStrand):
        position[i] = dict.fromkeys("ATGC",0)
        position[i][c] += 1

    #take a random fingerprint of size fpSize
    places = random.sample(range(n),fpSize)
    refPrint = takeFingerPrint(refStrand,places)
    s = smudges(refPrint)

    for strand in strandList[1:]:
        fp = takeFingerPrint(strand,places)
        if fp in s: #maybe a hit!
            if HammingClose(strand,refStrand):
                ncount += 1
                for i,c in enumerate(strand):
                    position[i][c] += 1


    #assemble summary strand

    mode = []
    for i in range(len(refStrand)):
        c = "A"
        m = position[i]["A"]
        for x in "TGC":
            if position[i][x] > m:
                c = x
                m = position[i][x]
        mode.append(c)

    return(ncount,''.join(mode))

#example problem

strand = randDNA(10000)
strandList = [mutate(strand,5) for i in range(10000)]

n,s = summary(strandList,100)
print(n, "close strands found")
print("First 30 positions in summary strand are ", s[:30])
```

Sample run:

```
158 close strands found
First 30 positions in summary strand are  CAAGGTCGTCGCCCATAAACGTTTTTCCCA
```

My code didn't address the problem of ties, but should be easily modifiable to do so.

Second version. You can replace the `ALPHA` in the code by whatever character set you are using. Fingerprints are now initial slices. I form the set of all strings at Hamming distance exactly one from the initial slice of the first line. Then on iteration I check if *either* the initial slice equals of the line equals the reference slice and the rest of the line is at Hamming distance at most 1 *or* if the initial slice is in the set of slices at Hamming distance 1, in which case the rest of the line must equal the rest of the first line. I am assuming that the Python interpreter can test strings for equality faster than it can execute a loop. The resulting code seems to run over twice as fast as my initial code:

```
import random

ALPHA = "ATGC"

def randDNA(n):
    return ''.join(random.choice(ALPHA) for i in range(n))

def mutate(strand,times):
    nucleotides = list(strand)
    n = len(strand)
    for i in range(times):
        j = random.randint(0,n-1)
        nucleotides[i] = random.choice(ALPHA)
    return ''.join(nucleotides)

def HammingOne(s,t):
    #assumes s and t are strings of the same length
    #returns True if s,t are Hamming distance 1
    #otherwise returns False

    clashes = 0
    for x,y in zip(s,t):
        if x != y:
            clashes += 1
            if clashes > 1: return False
    return True if clashes == 1 else False


def neighbors(s):
    n = set()
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        n.update([s[:i] + d + s[(i+1):] for d in ALPHA if d != c])
    return n

def summary(sList, fpSize = 10):
    n = len(sList)
    refString = sList[0]
    ncount = 0 #count of Hamming-neighbors
    position = {}

    for i,c in enumerate(refString):
        position[i] = dict.fromkeys(ALPHA,0)
        position[i][c] += 1


    refPrint = refString[:fpSize]
    s = neighbors(refPrint)
    refTail = refString[fpSize:]

    for strand in sList[1:]:
        fp = strand[:fpSize]
        if (fp == refPrint) and \
           (strand[fpSize:] == refTail or HammingOne(strand[fpSize:],refTail)) or \
           (HammingOne(fp,refPrint) and strand[fpSize:] == refTail):
            ncount += 1
            for i,c in enumerate(strand):
                position[i][c] += 1

    #assemble summary strand

    mode = []
    for i in range(len(refString)):
        c = ALPHA[0]
        m = position[i][c]
        for x in ALPHA[1:]:
            if position[i][x] > m:
                c = x
                m = position[i][x]
        mode.append(c)

    return(ncount,''.join(mode))

#example problem

strand = randDNA(10000)
sList = [mutate(strand,5) for i in range(10000)]

n,s = summary(sList,100)
print(n, "close strands found")
print("First 30 positions in summary strand are ", s[:30])
```

Comment: This looks good, i'll play around with this and see if it helps. I really appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: A variation of the idea is to let the fingerprint be an initial slice. Easier to extract, and if this initial slice is at Hamming distance one it suffices to simply check the rest of the string for equality.